# Typescript inference from arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm looking for a way to make Typescript guess the return type of my function according to the function arguments.

```
function fn<T extends object>(a: T, b: T, property: keyof T): any {
  return a[property] ?? b[property];
}
```

I want to remove `any` to get the proper return type.

```
interface A {
  foo?: string;
}

const a: A = { foo : 'bar' };
const b: A = {};
const a = fn(a, b, 'foo'); // it should get the string type from inference
```

I looked at `ReturnType<T>` by using it like this `ReturnType<typeof T[property]>` but it seems not supported by Typescript. I don't known if it's feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another type parameter for the property name:

```js
function fn<T, K extends keyof T>(a: T, b: T, property: K): T[K] {
  return a[property] ?? b[property];
}
```

Note that it will infer `string | undefined`, not `string`, because the `foo` property on the interface `A` is optional, so it's possible both `a` and `b` don't have it.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAKgGkQaUQUwA8p8wATAZ0QGt8BPOYRdAPgAoBDALmewCMeWRAAcATnGH5RUOjxwBKQQG0cAXUQBvAFCJEo-FBCikHJWIlSZ6gPzXEfM+MnS6qgNxaAvlq0wwJUWAOCHxEAEFNHWQ4OGseCihRPwBzD28tCAQExG5wxABeTWi4RB4Acj4OUTLETw9MsGyBPMKNOoysqERCAuQwTn5sMuAYsvkPLSA)